# Is this the proper way to reuse connections to an Azure Cosmos instance from a Web Job?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-webjobs

I have a web job in my Azure web app that writes data to an Azure Cosmos instance. This web is triggered from a storage queue. Each trigger spawns a new process to do one insert or one update to the Cosmos instance. With the amount of data coming into that queue, the web job inserts/updates the Azure Cosmos instance around 1000 times every minute.

In a separate, user-facing portal, the users query data from this Azure Cosmos instance. We have been getting a high number of these errors from that public-facing portal:

**Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted <>**

**An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full**

To me, this is indicative of SNAT port exhaustion. All documentation and help information on this subject, and on these specific error messages point to "ensuring that we are re-using connections to the Cosmos instance", and that we are using best practices. I "believe" we are re-using connections to the Azure Cosmos instance properly, but I am not sure. This is the code:

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageQueues();
        });
        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Functions.cs**

```
namespace WebhookMessageProcessor
{
    public class RingCentralMessageProcessor
    {
        private static List<KeyValuePair<string, CosmosClient>> cosmosClients = new List<KeyValuePair<string, CosmosClient>>();
        public async static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("<<storage-queue-name>>")] string message, ILogger logger)
        {
            var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebHookHandlerModel>(message);
            //the intention here is to maintain a list of cosmos clients, as each message from the queue indicates which Cosmos instance to update/insert the data to. For now, however, all messages are going to a single instance. More will be added later.
            if (cosmosClients == null) cosmosClients = new List<KeyValuePair<string, CosmosClient>>();
            await HandleCallData(model.ownerId, model.body, storageConnectionString);
        }
        public async static Task HandleCallData(string ownerId, string deserializedData, string storageConnectionString)
        {
            var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PushModel>(deserializedData);
            if (model == null || model.body == null || model.body.sessionId == null)
            {
                //log error
            }
            else
            {
                        //the intention here is to maintain a list of cosmos clients, as each message from the queue indicates which Cosmos instance to update/insert the data to. For now, however, all messages are going to a single instance. More will be added later.
                        var cosmosClient = null;
                        if (!cosmosClients.Any(x => x.Key == ownerId))
                        {
                            cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosConfig.accountEndpoint, cosmosConfig.accountKey);
                            cosmosClients.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, CosmosClient>(ownerId, cosmosClient));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cosmosClient = cosmosClients.First(x => x.Key == ownerId).Value;
                        }
                        //data building logic here
                        //...
                        var cosmosContainer = cosmosClient.GetContainer(cosmosConfig.databaseId, cosmosConfig.containerId);
                        string etag = null;
                        if (condition1) // THEN INSERT
                        {
                            var task = await cosmosContainer.CreateItemAsync(call, partitionKey: new PartitionKey(partitionKey), requestOptions: new ItemRequestOptions() { IfMatchEtag = etag });
                            success = true;
                        }
                        else if (condition2) // THEN FIND AND REPLACE
                        {
                            var response = await cosmosContainer.ReadItemAsync<CallIndex>(call.id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
                            var existingCallIndex = response.Resource;
                            etag = response.ETag;
                            await cosmosContainer.ReplaceItemAsync(existingCallIndex, call.id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey), new ItemRequestOptions() { IfMatchEtag = etag });
                            success = true;
                        }
                        else //  FIND AND REPLACE BY DEFAULT
                        {
                            var response = await cosmosContainer.ReadItemAsync<CallIndex>(call.id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
                            var existingCallIndex = response.Resource;
                            etag = response.ETag;
                            await cosmosContainer.ReplaceItemAsync(existingCallIndex, call.id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey), new ItemRequestOptions() { IfMatchEtag = etag });
                            success = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //handle exception here
                    }
                    curTries++;
                } while (!success && curTries < maxTries);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am maintaining a list of cosmos clients in a static variable, as the content of the message may indicate writing to a different cosmos instance. However, as of now, there is only one instance, and all data is going to that single instance. There will be more instances in the future. Is this a good/correct way to reuse connections to the Cosmos instance in my web job?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be technically achieved but there are trade-offs you need to make. Mainly latency (you can't have an unbounded list of Cosmos Clients on Direct mode).

- The `key` of Dictionary should be the account name, that way you don't end up creating multiple clients for the same account even if the "owner" is different. There should be a Singleton client per account your application interacts with.
- You should put your client on [Gateway mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes). This should use less ports, have higher potential latency, but there is no scenario where you can have an unbounded number of client instances on Direct mode, that simply will almost always hit your connection limit. [Example on how to change the connection mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3?tabs=trace-net-core#networking).
- You are using a List, that is neither concurrent nor handles eviction. You should dispose clients that are not used after some time or define a max number of clients you can handle, it's impossible to write an app that handles an unbounded/infinite number of clients. Maybe [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) is a good option. But you need to define a limit or make sure you can distribute across multiple machines/instances.

Comment: Thanks @Matias. This makes sense. I don't plan on having an unbounded list of those clients of course. And to your point about the key<->account - the owner is in fact the account name. And there is a single client in that list per account. I might try gateway mode as well. But the general idea is to have a list of 10-20 clients per instance, and that instance is responsible for processing data for those 10-20 clients.

Answer (score 1):

Putting Cosmos clients in a List will never work as you can't pool connections for different clients pointing at different accounts. Your single client instance here is likely hitting the 128 port max for your WebJob. For Cosmos you should use a single client per instance. You should also cache the container references too. Not doing this will cause 429s on the master partition (stores all your account meta data) in Cosmos DB due to all the meta data requests that will happen at larger request volumes.

Take a look at this article here on Singleton client, container reference caching and PortReuseMode
[Best Practices for .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/best-practice-dotnet)

Also see here for [Networking Performance Tips for .NET SDK v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3?tabs=trace-net-core#networking)

Comment: Thanks @Mark - even if the list object is static (as above)? I'm "trying" to use the singleton instance. But the only caveat is that I have more than one cosmos instance (all in the same region). That is what I'm trying to accommodate here. What is the difference between having a single static cosmos client object versus a single static list with a single cosmos client inside it?

Comment: You could explore using Service Endpoints to get around the problem at a small scale, but then you're likely going to run into a cap on network connections for a Web Apps instance. At some point you won't be able to scale up enough. The only way around that is to scale out.